# Reading Python Dictionary in Keras

Tags: pandas, keras

I am trying to adapt the Kaggle Facial Keypoint Detection tutorial and codes to solve a a similar problem. I am trying to detect four keypoint in the human body; Left shoulder, right shoulder, nose and neck.

I used  http://labelbox.com to label my images, but the format of the excel file I have now is two columns one with the image name and another one with a python dictionary like this:

```
{'LS': [{'geometry': {'x': 45, 'y': 21}}],
 'RS': [{'geometry': {'x': 28, 'y': 30}}],
 'Neck': [{'geometry': {'x': 38, 'y': 25}}],
 'Nose': [{'geometry': {'x': 50, 'y': 15}}]}
```

while Kaggle data set uses a column for each point component (one for x another for y for each point).

is there a good way to separate the final x and y values for each point into separate columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `pandas.io.json.json_normalize` as advised in the answer below by @tawab_shakeel, as follows where raw_data is read from csv file

```
import ast
def extract_data(raw_data):
    data_list=[]
    items = ['LS', 'RS', 'Neck', 'Nose']
    for row in raw_data.index: 
        #print(row)
        x = raw_data ['Label'][row]
        #print(type(x))
        x = ast.literal_eval(x)
        #print(type(x))
        if'LS' not in x:
            x= insert(x, {'fill_0':[{"geometry":{"x":45,"y":21}}]},0)
        if'RS' not in x:
            x= insert(x, {'fill_1':[{"geometry":{"x":45,"y":21}}]},1)
        if'Neck' not in x:
            x= insert(x, {'fill_2=':[{"geometry":{"x":45,"y":21}}]},2)
        if'Nose' not in x:
            x= insert(x, {'TEST_3':[{"geometry":{"x":45,"y":21}}]},3)
        list_main=[]
        point_index = 0
        for item in x:
            if item == items[point_index]:
                temp = dict()
                temp["tag"] = item
                x[item][0].update(temp)

               # print(list_main)
            else:
                x[item][0]['geometry']['x']=0
                x[item][0]['geometry']['y']=0
                x[item][0]['tag']= items[point_index]
            list_main.append(x[item][0])
            point_index +=1
        final_df = json_normalize(list_main)
        del final_df['tag']
        a = np.asarray(final_df)
        a = a.flatten()
        data_list.append(a)
    return data_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [pandas.io.json.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) to convert the dict into right dataframe format

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
list_main=[]
for item in data:
    temp = dict()
    temp["tag"] = item
    data[item][0].update(temp)
    list_main.append(data[item][0])

final_df = json_normalize(list_main)
```

```
  geometry.x    geometry.y  tag
0      45            21     LS
1      28            30     RS
2      38            25     Neck
3      50            15     Nose
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, How can I do this on a whole file.
The cell you processed is is in a row having another column telling the image name. 
So is there a way to flatten the two columns [geometry.x    geometry.y] to rows

Comment: I think I have a plan now, I follow this https://pythonspot.com/read-excel-with-pandas/ to read each column in my excel sheet into a list. then iterate over list elements with the code you provided.

Comment: @KaramAboGhalieh is your problem is solved or you have any confusion?

Comment: still working on starting from your code, I need to reach the following format
columns: LSX LSY RSX RSY NeckX NeckY NoseX NoseY ImageName 

what I have now is 
columns: Label ImageName 

where Label is in the format listed in the question.